# React.js components not rendering on html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rendering

I am trying to integrate some React.js into a website I am making. I have been trying to add a simple element to start off with, but it isn't displaying. There are no errors in the website console or the console of my editor.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Website</h1>

        <div id="react-container"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">
            import React from 'react';
            import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

            const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>


            ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("react-container"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried running the program in a localhost server, opening it in google chrome using the file path on my computer, and also with a microsoft edge previewer within vscode, but none of them show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since you are running the code in the browser you dont import react nor react DOM. Modules are whole topic on its own to learn, so here is the [further reading](https://codesweetly.com/javascript-modules-tutorial).

Second, you are missing a babel import. Babel is responsible for compiling the JSX `<Component />` syntax and also for `createElement` api.

Third, most common way of writing react components is function or arrow function `const Element = () => <h1>Hello world!</h1>`

Putting this all together, you need the following snippet in order to make it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Website</h1>

        <div id="react-container"></div>

        <script type="text/babel">

            const Element = () => <h1>Hello World</h1>

            ReactDOM.render(<Element />, document.getElementById("react-container"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you mentioned about not importing react or reactDOM. Does this extend to things like useState as well? Importing it throws up the same error as before, but leaving it without the import also throws up an error.

Comment: The React acts as a global namespace under the `React` object. The way for you to access things like `useState` in HTML (without actually running a server or create-react-app boilerplate) is same as the way ReactDOM calls render method. Say on the example above component Element becomes:

const Element = () => {
            const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState("Hello World");
            return <h1>{someState}</h1>
            }